# Android library not pulling its resources through to other projects

Tags: android, resources

I have an Android project that I'm trying to make into a library.  I get an exception thrown on this code:

```
_buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
```

The exception I get is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.xxx.libraryname.R$id.buttonStart
```

The Android docs seem to explicitly say that the library should be able to access those resources:

"For example, source code in the library project can access its own resources through its R class."

When I look in the library's `/gen/com.xxx.libraryname/R.java/R/id/`, buttonStart is there.  But when I look in the main project's `/gen/com.xxx.libraryname/R.java/R/id`, it isn't.

I've done a make clean.

Comment: Figured it out.  Both projects had a "main.xml" file.  Renamed the library's main.xml file and things worked.

Comment: Yes, if you have resources named the same, the host project wins. It is best to give libraries unique resource names, perhaps via some prefix notation, so there are no accidental collisions. There may still be *intentional* collisions, where the host is specifically trying to replace the resource, in which case the host has to do so in a way that the library will accept (e.g., maintaining the same widgets with the same IDs for layouts).

Comment: @DanJameson Can you also add the solution in the answers section?

Comment: Post the answer so that this question get so that it no longer remains unanswered.

Answer (score 4):

**Your library project also has same name layout main.xml as your main project.**

Android will give priority to host project if both have the same Layout name, in this case **"main.xml"** Best approach is to use some prefix notation so there are no accidental collisions.

Comment: can you explain more details ? i dont understand